# How to align data in a column ?

Tags: tables

Data in the my third column is not aligned. I would be grateful if you could help me to align and correct the format of my table.
[image]

```
\captionsetup{justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=sc,labelsep = newline}
        \renewcommand*\thetable{\Roman{table}}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{l||c||c{5cm}}
                \hhline{===}
                \rowcolor{mg}
                Security Level & Security Mode & Protection\\\hline
                \hhline{===} 
                0 & No Security      &\vtop{\hbox{\strut Data is not encrypted}\hbox{\strut Data authenticity is not validated}}\\\hline
                1 & AES-CBC-MAC-32   &\vtop{\hbox{\strut Data is not encrypted}\hbox{\strut Data authenticity using a 32-bit MIC}}\\\hline  
                2 & AES-CBC-MAC-64   &\vtop{\hbox{\strut Data is not encrypted}\hbox{\strut Data authenticity using 64-bit MIC}}\\\hline  
                3 & AES-CBC-MAC-128  &\vtop{\hbox{\strut Data is not encrypted}\hbox{\strut Data authenticity using 128-bit MIC}}\\\hline  
                4 & AES-CTR          &\vtop{\hbox{\strut Data is encrypted}\hbox{\strut Data authenticity is not validated}}\\\hline  
                5 & AES-CCM-32       &\vtop{\hbox{\strut Data is encrypted}\hbox{\strut Data authenticity using a 32-bit MIC}}\\\hline  
                6 & AES-CCM-64       &\vtop{\hbox{\strut Data is encrypted}\hbox{\strut Data authenticity using a 64-bit MIC}}\\\hline  
                7 & AES-CCM-128      &\vtop{\hbox{\strut Data is encrypted}\hbox{\strut Data authenticity using a 128-bit MIC}}\\\hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{\label{tab:tab1} {Security modes in the IEEE802.15.4e Standard. \cite{19}}}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: please provide a small test file that shows the problem,  and defines the commands you use. `\captionsetup` is not defined by default nor is `\hhline` and  `c{5cm}` would generate an error unless you have a non standard table definition. (also `\vtop` and `\hbox` are tex primitives that should never appear in a latex document)

Answer (score 2):

Besides the valuable comments by @DavidCarlisle, I don't recommend this style for tables at all, it has too many visual noise to be readable. I suggest using `booktabs` and removing all these vertical and horizontal rules for a cleaner and professional look. As a bonus, the markup is much simpler too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=sc,labelsep = newline}
        \renewcommand*\thetable{\Roman{table}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}clX@{}}
  \toprule
  Security Level & Security Mode & Protection \\
  \midrule
  0 & No Security     & Data is not encrypted \newline Data authenticity is not validated   \\ 
  1 & AES-CBC-MAC-32  & Data is not encrypted \newline Data authenticity using a 32-bit MIC \\   
  2 & AES-CBC-MAC-64  & Data is not encrypted \newline Data authenticity using 64-bit MIC   \\   
  3 & AES-CBC-MAC-128 & Data is not encrypted \newline Data authenticity using 128-bit MIC  \\   
  4 & AES-CTR         & Data is encrypted \newline Data authenticity is not validated       \\   
  5 & AES-CCM-32      & Data is encrypted \newline Data authenticity using a 32-bit MIC     \\   
  6 & AES-CCM-64      & Data is encrypted \newline Data authenticity using a 64-bit MIC     \\   
  7 & AES-CCM-128     & Data is encrypted \newline Data authenticity using a 128-bit MIC    \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{\label{tab:tab1} {Security modes in the IEEE802.15.4e Standard. \cite{19}}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: thank you very much  for your answer, but the third column's length is very  big.